# Electron, Typescript, React - A webpack issue

Tags: typescript, webpack, electron

I'm trying to get these 3 to play nice together, for the most part - they do, unless I try to use `fs` or similar modules from nodejs.

Figured out that I need to use `externals`, found out about a package called `nodeExternals`, to not package things that the environment will provide. My snipper is as follows:

```
target: "electron-renderer",
externals: [
    nodeExternals({
        path: "./node_modules",
        whitelist: ["react", "react-dom", "gphoto2"],
    }),
],
```

And the error I'm getting is:

```
external_"object-assign":1 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
at eval (external_"object-assign":1)
at Object.object-assign (renderer.bundle.js:291)
at __webpack_require__ (renderer.bundle.js:20)
at eval (react.development.js:18)
at eval (react.development.js:1900)
at Object../node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js (renderer.bundle.js:166)
at __webpack_require__ (renderer.bundle.js:20)
at eval (index.js:4)
at Object../node_modules/react/index.js (renderer.bundle.js:178)
at __webpack_require__ (renderer.bundle.js:20)
```

I used these resources:

- https://github.com/Robinfr/electron-react-typescript
- https://taraksharma.com/setting-up-electron-typescript-react-webpack/

Can I get some hints/explanation what is going on here? I am kinda lost.

Comment: There is a workaround by using require this way `const electron = window.require('electron'); const fs = electron.remote.require('fs');const ipcRenderer  = electron.ipcRenderer;` Your BrowserWindow needs the option `nodeintegration:true` for this though.

Comment: @Rhayene A bit more information would be appriciated :)

Comment: Ah, sorry ^^" I was refering to [this electron issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/7300) and to [this tutorial](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/building-an-electron-application-with-create-react-app-97945861647c/). I didn't write it as an answer as it may not be your problem, but I still thought it may help you a little.

Comment: I made a boiler plate starter pack which contains many bug fixes that are found when using react with electron and typescript and has auto monitoring of typescript changes to reload the electron app for faster development.

https://github.com/nateshmbhat/electron-react-ts-starter/